# Use Variable for Attribute in XPath

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to use the variable $Identifier as an attribute value in a XPath to look up some Information depending on the current $Identifier.

```
    <xsl:when test="self::ATTRIBUTE-VALUE-XHTML">
        <xsl:variable name="Identifier" select="./DEFINITION/ATTRIBUTE-DEFINITION-STRING-REF"/>
        <xsl:variable name="LongName" select="concat('/SPEC-OBJECT-TYPE/SPEC-ATTRIBUTES/node()[@IDENTIFIER=', $Identifier, ']/@LONG-NAME')"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$LongName}">Test</xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
```

I tried to use concat() to combine the path and variable $Identifier:

```
<xsl:variable name="LongName" select="concat('/SPEC-OBJECT-TYPE/SPEC-ATTRIBUTES/node()[@IDENTIFIER=', $Identifier, ']/@LONG-NAME')"/>
```

But that didn't work. How can I get the variable to work in the Path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this....

```
<xsl:variable name="LongName" select="/SPEC-OBJECT-TYPE/SPEC-ATTRIBUTES/node()[@IDENTIFIER=$Identifier]/@LONG-NAME')"/>
```

(Your current variable is actually just a string, and you would need to use some form of dynamic evaluation for that to work).

As an aside, you could also use a key here...

```
<xsl:key name="test" match="/SPEC-OBJECT-TYPE/SPEC-ATTRIBUTES/node()" use="@IDENTIFIER" />
```

Then your `LongName` variable becomes this...

```
<xsl:variable name="LongName" select="key('test', $Identifier)"/>
```